# How to use View Based Authorization in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting weird behavior in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app where the authorization passes at the controller level and fails at the view level.

Is this a bug in ASP.NET Core 2.0 or am I doing something wrong in my code?

//Successful authorization in Controller

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
      Authorization was successful for user: (username).

//Entry into Controller

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method HomeController.Index (Bams) with arguments ((null)
) - ModelState is Valid

...

//Failure in View

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: (username).

ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("HasName", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasNameRequirement()));
});
```

HomeController.cs:

```
[Authorize(Policy="HasName")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(){
        return View();
    }
}
```

HasNameRequirement:

```
public class HasNameRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement {
    public HasNameRequirement() { }
}
```

HasNameHandler:

```
public class HasNameHandler : AuthorizationHandler<HasNameRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, HasNameRequirement requirement)
    {
        var mvcContext = context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext;
        if (mvcContext != null)
        {
            var name = mvcContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            if(name != null && name != "")
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
        }           

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@if (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "HasName"))
{
    ...
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService
```

Comment: Why are you doing authZ in your view?

Comment: @Mardoxx The intention is that there is going to be certain links and content that are only visible to those with the proper claims. I don't want a link to a User Administration page to show up if the controller is going to lock them out anyway. In the actual version of the code I will have different policies. This was just testing the functionality of view based authorization. I'm open to other suggestions but creating separate views for each policy is not something I am willing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the HasNameHandler.

```
var mvcContext = context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext;
```

This line made is so that my authorization block only worked when there was an MVC context. Because the view doesn't have access to the MVC context, the view-based authorization finished the authorization without hitting a context.Succeed().

I removed that and instead used the AuthorizationContext passed into the method.

```
var name = context.User.Identity.Name;
if(name != null && name != ""){
    context.Succeed(requirement);
}
else {
    context.Fail();
}
```